# In switchMap return promise or the real object

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-routing

From the angular tutorial code, I would like to use the hero-details.component to update and create hero object.

So I add the route without id.

Route

```
  {
    path:'detail/:id',
    component:HeroDetailComponent
  },
  {
    path:'detail',
    component:HeroDetailComponent
  }
```

The hero service

```
getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
    return this.getHeroes()
    .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
}
```

But then I don't know how to handle in the hero-details.component file.
In the switchMap, if there is no id in the Url I want to return a new Hero. But if I had an id I called the service which return a `Promise<Hero>` object.
This doesn't compile

```
ngOnInit():void{
    this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params:ParamMap) => {
          var id = +params['id'];
          return id ? this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']) : new Hero();
      })
      .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
  }
```

What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.route.paramMap
  .switchMap((params:ParamMap) => {
    const idAsString = params.get('id');
    return idAsString ? 
      Observable.from(this.heroService.getHero(+idAsString)) :
      Observable.of(new Hero());
  })
  .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
```

Or, if there no link from this route to this same route, you could just use the snapshot:

```
const idAsString = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
if (idAsString) {
  this.heroService.getHero(+idAsString).then(hero => this.hero = hero);
}
else {
  this.hero = new Hero();
}
```